# How to update DLL with latest version in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, c#-4.0, servicestack

I need to ask the idea about upgrading DLL with latest version without removing it from References manually.

For example, In my project, I am using **ServiceStack** DLL which has version : **4.0.52.0** but I want to update it with version **4.5.6**

Is there any specific way available in Visual Studio 2013, so that I can download and update DLL References with Latest DLL.

Thanks

Comment: NuGet packages?

Comment: NuGet only update package library. If I am using something else from third party then?

Comment: What you describe is exactly NuGet packages. You want to have the same feature outside of the system, which is not possible. You will need to download the DLL yourself and update the reference manually (unless you can find a NuGet package for this DLL)

Comment: As a matter of fact this is available on NuGet... https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack/

Answer (score 4):

Use a NuGet package instead of a manual reference.

The DLL you are looking for can be found as a NuGet package here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack/